# What is the difference between the offered MySQL Server downloads?

Tags: mysql, wamp

I'm writing web applications mostly under LAMP (linux, apache, mysql, php). Now I have to work on a Windows XP machine but I'm not sure which MySQL release to download.

On the [download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) there are 3 ZIP archives and 2 MSI installers. Some of them are about 30 mb and some - 150 mb. Unfortunately there is nothing to highlight the differences.

Answer (score 1):

- `mysql-5.5.25a.zip` is the source code of the MySQL Community Server.
- `mysql-5.5.25a-win32.zip` is the compiled, 32-bit version of the MySQL Community Server.
- `mysql-5.5.25a-win64.zip` is the compiled, 64-bit version of the MySQL Community Server.

The `.msi` versions are *installers* of the 32/64bit version. I would recommend you pick one of these two, depending on your workstation.

Comment: Do compiled versions (zip archives) provide more flexability in terms of customisation ?

Comment: @TichomirMitkov: I haven't installed them. But I would doubt it. When working on Windows, you might even find it easier to use something like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).